# Mockito mismatch method signature on SpringData findAll(Pageable)

Tags: spring-data, mockito, spring-data-mongodb

This is puzzling and weirdly my search didn't lead to any answer.
I've a pretty straightforward SpringData Mongo Repository and I'm trying to test a Controller using such repository. The controller calls the `findAll(Pageable)` on the repository, so I wish to mock such invocation using Mockito:

```
Page<Idea> page = new PageImpl<Idea>(
            IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> Idea.builder().title("idea-" + i).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

when(repo.findAll(any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(page);
```

But that leads to a puzzling compilation error:

> The method findAll(Sort) in the type MongoRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Matcher<Pageable>)

Apparently Mockito picks up the wrong method, but why? `Pageable` is an interface and it does not extend `Sort`! I also tried defining a `findAll(Pageable)` abstract method on the repository, but it then reports a class mismatch: `Matcher<Pageable>` (the call) does not match `Pageable` (the definition).

I'm lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aww! Found a solution so, may be others will find this useful.

The culprit was about the matcher method I used: the `any()` I was using above was from `org.hamcrest.Matchers`, instead of `org.mockito.Matchers`. I believe my IDE didn't pick the right one because the latter has now been deprecated in favour of `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`.